# Macbook OS v10.11.6 Can't Open Blender

Tags: osx

I am getting the following error message...

"The application “Blender” can’t be opened."

No follow up information, no "...because we can't identify the developer, etc.," just that.

Please help!

Comment: A user that had the same "Blender can't be opened" error posted [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?324945-Latest-Development-for-Fluid-Designer&p=2852210&viewfull=1#post2852210) The answer for them was [this response by RyanMDev](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?324945-Latest-Development-for-Fluid-Designer&p=2852688&viewfull=1#post2852688) "Try re-downloading the app, "... "and make sure you use "Archive Utility" to decompress the zip file, sometimes other zip tools can corrupt the file."

Answer (score 1):

go to security and privacy and click on general then click on open anyway

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences.

[image]

Then go to Security & Privacy

[image]

Click on "Open Anyway"

[image]